# <NSInternalInconsistencyException> Invalid update: invalid number of sections

Tags: xcode, tableview

I am adding user defined text in a UItableView via a modal view controller. 
The table is created as a NSMutableArray. on entering data in the modal view and tapping a Done button a  Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  error is generated.
I must update the array when the user enters data but not sure how to do that. I have attached the relevant code. Thanks for your advice.

```
//Number of sections
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { return 1; } 
//Number of rows
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  [listOfConjProcedures count];
}

//Loading the cells
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    // Configure the cell.

    cell.textLabel.text = [listOfConjProcedures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

//Done button Delegate for the modal view
- (void)itemDetailViewController:(ItemDetailViewController *)controller didFinishAddingItem:(ChecklistItem *)item
{
    int newRowIndex = [listOfConjProcedures indexOfObject:item];
    [listOfConjProcedures addObject:item];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:0];
    NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: What does your numberOfSections method look like?

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
  
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem may be here:

```
int newRowIndex = [listOfConjProcedures indexOfObject:item];
```

This wouldn't have an index unless you'd already added it to the array, but in the next line you add it to the array, so it doesn't make sense.

I think you are therefore adding a row at index path 0,NSNotFound, which will confuse the table view. Either use the count of the array as the row index, or insert your new row at the start (0,0) of the table (and at index 0 of the array).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Item is defined in another section of code and is supposed to store the text from the UItextfield in the modal view `- (IBAction)done
{
    ChecklistItem *item = [[ChecklistItem alloc] init];
    item.text = self.textField.text;
    item.checked = NO;
    
    [self.delegate itemDetailViewController:self didFinishAddingItem:item];
}`

Comment: Yes, but if it is not already in your listOfProcedures array you will get NSNotFound as your index, which you then use to build an invalid index path.

Comment: Thank you for your help changed to item.text as this is what I have configured the UIlabel to in the modal view controller